# Error when loading geforce experience

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I Hope someone is able to help me here, yesterday after updating my 980ti driver i went to open geforce experience to check some shadowplay settings, and as soon as it open i get a error message saying "geforce experience has encountered a problem and needs to close", i did some research and people say about uninstalling and reinstalling, i will list everything i have tried so far.

I have reinstalled geforce experience by downloading the latest version from the geforce website.
I have reinstalled the graphics driver using clean install and selecting geforce experience in the list of optional installs.
I have gone to a very old version of geforce experience such as 1.7.1 and the same error persists.
I have rolled back to a older graphics driver and the same error persists.

My operating system is Windows 10 pro 64bit.
And all updates are up to date.

I hope someone is able to help.

Thank you in advance.

Found this in GfeClientLog if this means anything to anyone ?
2016-03-25 11:18:20,943 [Main]  ERROR GFEClientCore.Common.RegistrySettings(GetValue) - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

A recent YouTube video explains one solution.

- Uninstall GeForce Experience and your graphics card driver, but do not restart when prompted to do so
- Disable .NET Framework 3.5 + 4.0
- Restart your computer
- Enable .NET Framework 3.5 + 4.0
- Reinstall GeForce Experience and your graphics card driver

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zri4g2xYKZM

Comment: Many thanks for this, will try this out once i leave work tonight and get back to you.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Delay on reply but thought i should update this letting people know i had to reinstall window to fix the issue, it was a problem in window that was the issue, and repairs did not work.

Comment: You should post that as an answer so people can more easily find your solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to reinstall the OS, some of my windows files had corrupted and none of the fixes worked.